# when specifice page in url, sinatra not enforcing authentication

Tags: ruby, sinatra, protected

If I go in with localhost:4567, I get prompted for username and password, but if I go in with localhost:4567/MyStaticPage.htm, it goes right to that page, i.e., without any authentication (and yes, I stopped and restarted sinatra,  and closed and reopened my browser) .  I put "puts" statements in the "get"s to see what's getting run, and the url with "MyStaticPage.htm" does not seem to be handled in the "get" I would expect.  Here's the code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

helpers do

  def protected!
    unless authorized?
      response['WWW-Authenticate'] = %(Basic realm="Restricted Area")
      throw(:halt, [401, "Not authorized\n"])
    end
  end

  def authorized?
    @auth ||=  Rack::Auth::Basic::Request.new(request.env)
    @auth.provided? && @auth.basic? && @auth.credentials && @auth.credentials ==     ['testuser', 'testpassword']
  end

end

get '/MyStaticPage.htm' do
  puts "this is never seen"
  protected!
  File.new('public/MyStaticPage.htm').readlines
end

get '/' do
  puts "this is seen"
  protected!
  File.new('public/MyStaticPage.htm').readlines
end
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably the static files are served before your routes. Don't put those .htm files into the public folder and everything will work out nicely.

Philip

Comment: Thank you for that, I put the files in a subfolder called "private", and now the doc is secured; however, the only place I can keep the associated image files if I want them to appear on the page is the /public folder; I tried putting them in /private and /private/images (and rewriting the html), but they  don't appear. In my img tag I tried 'src="./private/image001.gif"' and 'src="/private/image001.gif"' and 'src="image001.gif"', but none work.

Comment: Nevermind, got it. I put the images in a subfolder of private, "images", and used the path, e.g., "images/image1.gif".  Thanks again

Comment: Oh great... Otherwise my bet was that a wrong content-type was default. Might still interest you: http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Mime%20Types